# Need the formula for a holiday pay of 8 hours on 1/1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with a formula please.
If cell c2 is a date of 1/1/2024 than cell L = 8.

Please help write this formula.

Comment: Is this what you mean `=IF(C2=DATE(2024,1,1),8,"")`? and is it for only `1/1`?

Comment: “I need help with a formula please. […] Please help write this formula.” And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: Could you please share us with a sample for more details, such as the cell format in C2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IF()` / `IFS()` / `SWITCH()`

```
=IF(C2=DATE(2024,1,1),8,"")
```

---

```
=IFS(C2=--"1/1/2024",8,TRUE,"")
```

---

```
=SWITCH(C2,DATE(2024,1,1),8,"")
```

---

Read **MSFT Documentations** for the above used functions. **[IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), [IFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)** and **[SWITCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e)**